# Input value in HTML

Tags: php, html

How do you a class id into an input field?

```
<input type="text" name="loc" value="<p id='test'>bb</p>" />
```

The example above doesn't work properly. Also, how do I put a PHP echo command in it.

Comment: what do you mean by `class id`?

Comment: just want the code work correctly, when I load it want in the field to have "bb"

Comment: <input type="text" name="loc1" value="<div id='test'> bb </div>" />

Answer (score 1):

Use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
<input type="text" name="loc" value="<?php echo htmlentities("<p id='test'>bb</p>"); ?>" />
```

The output will look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="loc" value="&lt;p id='test'&gt;bb&lt;/p&gt;" />
```

Comment: Same result..
for now I just want to use value: <p id='demo2'>&nbsp;</p>